# How to change theme of KDE-Plasma task bar

Tags: kde-plasma-5

I have a new Manjaro istallation using KDE Plasma

I have selected Breeze as a global theme and Breeze for Plasma style

I cannot find the setting to change the theme of the task bar. It is dark (other elements are light)

[image: Dark themed task bar]

How can I change it to

[image: Light themed task bar]

Comment: There's no setting to change the task bar only.

Comment: OK - What changes the task bar theme? Something must

Comment: The theme itself. You'd need to modify whatever theme you're applying.

Comment: Which theme lloks like the one I want - can't seem to fine it

Comment: I don't know and that's a product request which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to reboot and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1228953)

Comment: @Dominique there is no other answer posted. OP cannot accept an answer that is not posted. ChanganAugo merely made a comment. I don't see the comment where a reboot was selected, so it seems OP determined the next step themselves based on the info ChanganAuto provided. This is an answer, albeit awkwardly worded for this site.